# Producing a List from a ResultSet

Tags: kotlin, jdbc, sequence, resultset

I'm not entirely sure this is possible, and I definitely don't know what to search or how to concisely explain it, but this seems like quite a kotlin-y thing which I wouldn't be surprised if it was possible.

I want to instantiate a list with `listOf()` but instead of providing the elements for the list, providing some code which produces the elements for the list.

For example, using a ResultSet: (This isn't valid code)

```
val list: List<Int> = listOf(
    while(resultSet.next()){
        return resultSet.getInt(1)
    }
)
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: If you want a general solution for mapping a `ResultSet` to an `Iterable` or a `List`, there are a number of ways to define extension functions on it to do so. Otherwise, since `ResultSet` doesn't extend these interfaces that are easy to work with in Kotlin, if you only need to do this once, the trivial solution of just iterating over the set and adding every element to a mutable list is probably the best one.

Comment: @zsmb13 Yeah, I added an extension function and implemented it as you suggested in this case, but my question was more out of curiosity prompted by this specific use case than it was specifically about ResultSets

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`ResultSet` does not have the best interface for doing this type of transformation.  But it would look something like:

```
val list = resultSet.use {
    generateSequence {
        if (resultSet.next()) resultSet.getInt(1) else null
    }.toList()  // must be inside the use() block
} 

// resultSet is already closed automatically at this point
```

*See also:  [`generateSequence()`](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/generate-sequence.html)*

---

If you want to leave it as a `Sequence` instead of a `List` to process it lazily, you cannot use the [`.use()`](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/use.html) auto-closing helper.

```
val seq = generateSequence {
    if (resultSet.next()) resultSet.getInt(1) else null
}

// later remember to call resultSet.close(), since the resultSet is still open
```

---

With Kotlin 1.1 experimental [coroutines](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines.html) you can:

```
val seq = buildSequence {
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        yield(resultSet.getInt(1))
    }

    // resultSet.close() might work ok here
}

// if not, later remember to resultSet.close()
```

*See also:  [`buildSequence()`](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines.experimental/build-sequence.html)*

Comment: These are great and very useful, thank you very much! Just a small side note if used in the OSGi environment - `.use {}` requires `kotlin-stdlib-jdk7` that is NOT OSGi compliant so unfortunatelly it seems it is necessary to close the `resultSet` manually.

Comment: it's even easer to generate the sequence like this `generateSequence { resultSet.takeIf { it.next() } }`

Comment: @qoomon The following does not work: `val resultList = result.use { generateSequence { doSomethingWithResultSetReturnObject(it).takeIf { _ -> it.next() } }.toList() }`

Comment: @Splitframe I think `.takeIf { _ -> it.next() }` should be`.takeIf { it.next() }`

Comment: That would try to call `next()` on whatever the function returns, in this/my case a string. I had to give the lambda variable some identifier so that it doesn't overshadow the " it " of the ResultSet. After some testing I found out that it runs if you call `it.next()` before the `generateSequence` once, but then the first element is missing. So I had to resort to the good ol' `while(rs.next())` which is kind of a shame.

Answer (score 1):

It just occured to me that you could use `generateSequence` too. Props to Jayson for getting to it quicker ^^

This is what I came up with (not tested, but fairly short):

```
val list = generateSequence {
    if(!resultSet.next()) null
    else resultSet.getInt(1)
}.toList()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since kotlin 1.3

```
sequence {
    while (rs.next()) {
        yield(rs.getString(1))
    }
}.toList(
```

Answer (score 1):

The sequence approach can be made a bit more general by factoring out the value "extraction":

```kotlin
fun <T> ResultSet.asSequence( extract: () -> T ) : Sequence<T> = generateSequence {
        if (this.next()) extract() else null
    }
```

and then use it like so:

```kotlin
resultSet.asSequence { resultSet.getString(1) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the original question was about a list and not a sequence (covered in the other answers) the best solution would be to use a list builder introduced in kotlin v1.6.

```
val list = buildList{
    if(resultSet.next()) add(resultSet.getInt(1))
}
```

Clearly, `getInt` would need to be replaced with the actual attributes of interest.